# difference in behaviour between declaration in .pyd and .pyx files

Tags: cython, cythonize

I have a pxd file that declares some types with ctypedef, and some functions with cdef. To call one particular function, I have to duplicate the typedefs in my pyx file.

If I move the cdef of the function into the pyx file it fails to compile with "Cannot convert 'state_t *' to Python object". The error refers to this line of code

```
retval = c_explanation.table_of_states_is_bad(<state_t*>test_array, b)
```

The test_array parameter is created locally with malloc so is not a python object at all.

If remove the typedefs from the pyx file and import them and the cdef from the pxd file with a from .. import *, I get the same compile error.

The only way that I can get this simple bit of code to work is with the rather awkward duplication of typedefs in both pyx and pxd files.

Any thoughts on what is going on here and how to resolve it?

The full code is pasted below

---

pyx file

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

cimport c_explanation

cdef extern from "explanation.h":

    ctypedef int state_id;

    ctypedef struct event_t:
        pass

    ctypedef void (*event_handler)(event_t event)

    ctypedef struct state_t:
        state_id id
        event_handler handle
        char *name

    ctypedef enum bool:
        pass

def table_of_states_is_bad(a, b):
    cdef state_t *test_array
    cdef bool retval
    test_array = <state_t*>malloc(len(a) * sizeof(state_t))
    if not test_array:
        raise MemoryError()
    try:
        for i, s in enumerate(a):
            test_array[i].id = s[0]
        retval = c_explanation.table_of_states_is_bad(test_array, b)
        return retval
    finally:
      free(test_array)
```

---

pxd file

```
cdef extern from "explanation.h":

cdef int mock_get_temp(int)

ctypedef enum bool:
    pass

ctypedef struct event_t:
    pass

ctypedef void (*event_handler)(event_t event);

ctypedef int state_id;

ctypedef struct state_t:
    state_id id
    event_handler handle
    char *name

cdef bool table_of_states_is_bad(state_t table[], size_t size)
```

---

finally the h file

```
int mock_get_temp(int);

typedef int event_id;

/* an event */
typedef struct {
    event_id id;  /* numeric id */
    void *data;  /* points to anything */
    char *name;  /* points to string for debug or log */
} event_t;

typedef void (*event_handler)(event_t event);

typedef enum { false, true } bool;

typedef int state_id;

/* a state */
typedef struct {
    state_id id;  /* numeric id */
    event_handler handle;  /* points to handler */
    char *name;  /* points to string for debug or log */
} state_t;

bool table_of_states_is_bad(state_t table[], size_t size);
```

Comment: Your probability of getting an answer is higher, if you make your example minimal (as in [mcve]) and not just dump the whole code.

Comment: And the title of your question doesn't make a lot of sense (do you mean pxd and not pyd?)

Comment: The filenames aren't given in the question and are an important detail. Since your pxd file pre-declares the contents of you pyx file it should have the same name. It then _should not be cimported_.

Answer (score 0):

After some reading and experimentation I worked out what I had done wrong.

The problem is one of namespaces. When using the import * format, the local definition of table_of_states_is_bad() was replacing the imported one. Thus the function call was to the  cython version of the function rather than to the c version and hence the error was correctly reported.

I solved the problem by renaming the local function to wrap_table_of_states_is_bad() hence resolving the name conflict.